# trigger the change event in jquery, weird behaviour

Tags: jquery, events

I need to programmatically trigger the change event. This I can usually do, but I've found an unexplainable scenario which I hope you can help me with. I have this code:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {

    jQuery('.posts-list').hide();
    jQuery('.clinic').hide();

    jQuery('#category').change(function() {
        jQuery('.posts-list').hide();
        jQuery('#clinics-'+jQuery(this).val()).show().change();
    });

    jQuery('.posts-list').change(function() {
        jQuery('.clinic').hide();
        jQuery('#clinic-'+jQuery(this).val()).show();
    });

    jQuery('#category').change();
});
```

The important part of this code is the second to last line, and the function that's been bound to the change event of #category. The triggering of the change event inside that event actually works. But the triggering of the change event on the second to last line does not. If I put that into the console the first thing I do after having loaded the page, however, it works.

Anyone got an explanation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
jQuery('#category').trigger('change');
```

You actually want to trigger the event, rather than run the function.  Let me know if this helps.

Comment: That works! What distinguishes trigger('change') from simply .change(), do you know?

Comment: I do see that the documentation leads us to believe they are the same... but I've never had that experience.

Comment: That is very strange.  The documentation seems to imply that it is just an alias.

Comment: Perhaps it is because of the dependent events where .post-lists and #category both have change events.